# Mozilla Crash Reporter

Tags: firefox

I get this message every couple of days:
[image]

The full report is:

```
AdapterDeviceID: 0x1912
AdapterDriverVersion: 27.20.100.8682
AdapterSubsysID: 00000000
AdapterVendorID: 0x8086
AvailablePageFile: 30856196096
AvailablePhysicalMemory: 25422229504
AvailableVirtualMemory: 138531437330432
BuildID: 20210921185902
CPUMicrocodeVersion: 0xcc
ContentSandboxCapable: 1
ContentSandboxLevel: 6
CrashTime: 1632448269
InstallTime: 1632448197
LauncherProcessState: 0
ModuleSignatureInfo: {"Microsoft Corporation":["msvcp140.dll","VCRUNTIME140.dll","VCRUNTIME140_1.dll"],"Microsoft Windows":["msi.dll","wscapi.dll","AudioSes.dll","winrnr.dll","wshbth.dll","pnrpnsp.dll","NapiNSP.dll","Windows.Globalization.dll","DWrite.dll","ondemandconnroutehelper.dll","dbgcore.dll","iertutil.dll","urlmon.dll","dbghelp.dll","winmm.dll","BCP47mrm.dll","icm32.dll","InputHost.dll","TextInputFramework.dll","Windows.UI.dll","Bcp47Langs.dll","usp10.dll","ColorAdapterClient.dll","mscms.dll","rasadhlp.dll","MMDevAPI.dll","wininet.dll","npmproxy.dll","twinapi.appcore.dll","winhttp.dll","WindowManagementAPI.dll","FWPUCLNT.DLL","srvcli.dll","dhcpcsvc.dll","dhcpcsvc6.DLL","avrt.dll","winnsi.dll","version.dll","netprofm.dll","propsys.dll","nlaapi.dll","wsock32.dll","wtsapi32.dll","WinTypes.dll","dcomp.dll","CoreUIComponents.dll","CoreMessaging.dll","uxtheme.dll","dwmapi.dll","kernel.appcore.dll","windows.storage.dll","dxgi.dll","ntmarta.dll","rsaenh.dll","IPHLPAPI.DLL","dnsapi.dll","netutils.dll","mswsock.dll","CRYPTBASE.DLL","wldp.dll","cryptsp.dll","msasn1.dll","devobj.dll","umpdc.dll","powrprof.dll","sspicli.dll","userenv.dll","profapi.dll","bcryptPrimitives.dll","msvcp_win.dll","cfgmgr32.dll","wintrust.dll","gdi32full.dll","bcrypt.dll","KERNELBASE.dll","win32u.dll","ucrtbase.dll","crypt32.dll","kernel32.dll","setupapi.dll","oleaut32.dll","msctf.dll","clbcatq.dll","imm32.dll","shell32.dll","advapi32.dll","nsi.dll","user32.dll","msvcrt.dll","sechost.dll","combase.dll","psapi.dll","imagehlp.dll","rpcrt4.dll","SHCore.dll","shlwapi.dll","gdi32.dll","ole32.dll","ws2_32.dll","ntdll.dll"],"Mozilla Corporation":["firefox.exe","xul.dll","freebl3.dll","nss3.dll","mozglue.dll","nssckbi.dll","softokn3.dll","lgpllibs.dll"]}
MozCrashReason: MOZ_CRASH(Shutdown hanging after all known phases and workers finished.)
Notes: FP(D00-L1000-W00001000-T000) 
DWrite? DWrite+ WR? WR+ 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: aurora
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 100589
ShutdownProgress: xpcom-shutdown
StartupCrash: 0
StartupTime: 1632448197
SystemMemoryUsePercentage: 25
ThreadIdNameMapping: 15652:"IPC I/O Parent",21968:"JS Watchdog",20336:"TaskController Thread #0",7380:"TaskController Thread #1",12476:"TaskController Thread #2",17548:"TaskController Thread #3",9772:"TaskController Thread #4",24328:"TaskController Thread #5",5984:"TaskController Thread #6",24556:"TaskController Thread #7",21152:"WindowsVsyncThread",4716:"WRWorker#1",15856:"WRWorker#0",10784:"WRWorker#2",17456:"WRWorker#3",11376:"WRWorker#4",17420:"WRWorker#6",17572:"WRWorker#5",18328:"WRWorker#7",11028:"WRWorkerLP#0",21844:"WRWorkerLP#1",20632:"WRWorkerLP#2",1636:"WRWorkerLP#3",8516:"WRWorkerLP#4",5824:"WRWorkerLP#5",1928:"WRWorkerLP#6",23508:"WRWorkerLP#7",19032:"BitsCommander",23660:"Shutdown Hang Terminator",17528:"Shutdown Statistics Writer",
Throttleable: 1
TotalPageFile: 39441178624
TotalPhysicalMemory: 34224513024
TotalVirtualMemory: 140737488224256
URL: 
UptimeTS: 722.78613
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 93.0
Winsock_LSP: MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP] : 2 : 2 : 1 : 6 : 0x20066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : e70f1aa0-ab8b-11cf-8ca3-00805f48a192 
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IP] : 2 : 2 : 2 : 17 : 0x20609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : e70f1aa0-ab8b-11cf-8ca3-00805f48a192 
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IP] : 2 : 2 : 3 : 0 : 0x20609 : 0xc : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : e70f1aa0-ab8b-11cf-8ca3-00805f48a192 
 MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IPv6] : 2 : 23 : 1 : 6 : 0x20066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : f9eab0c0-26d4-11d0-bbbf-00aa006c34e4 
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IPv6] : 2 : 23 : 2 : 17 : 0x20609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : f9eab0c0-26d4-11d0-bbbf-00aa006c34e4 
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IPv6] : 2 : 23 : 3 : 0 : 0x20609 : 0xc : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : f9eab0c0-26d4-11d0-bbbf-00aa006c34e4 
 AF_UNIX : 2 : 1 : 1 : 0 : 0x20026 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : a00943d9-9c2e-4633-9b59-0057a3160994 
 RSVP TCPv6 Service Provider : 2 : 23 : 1 : 6 : 0x22066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 RSVP TCP Service Provider : 2 : 2 : 1 : 6 : 0x22066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 RSVP UDPv6 Service Provider : 2 : 23 : 2 : 17 : 0x22609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 RSVP UDP Service Provider : 2 : 2 : 2 : 17 : 0x22609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 Hyper-V RAW : 2 : 34 : 1 : 1 : 0x20026 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 1234191b-4bf7-4ca7-86e0-dfd7c32b5445 
 MSAFD L2CAP [Bluetooth] : 2 : 32 : 1 : 256 : 0x20006 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9fc48064-7298-43e4-b7bd-181f2089792a 
 MSAFD RfComm [Bluetooth] : 2 : 32 : 1 : 3 : 0x20026 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9fc48064-7298-43e4-b7bd-181f2089792a
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

What can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: To be clear: do you want to skip the reporter (so Firefox will crash less verbosely)? or to fix whatever causes your Firefox to crash (so Firefox won't crash in the first place)?

Comment: Please do not repost the exact same question. You can edit your original question to add more details.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, fix